# AWS CDK ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService with Node.js and WebSockets constantly stops after each health check

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, websocket, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I used **CDK** with the `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService` construct to deploy the **ECS Fargate** service with **Load Balancing**. It's the **WebSocket** API written on **Node.js** with **Socket.io**.

It works fine locally, but in the AWS it's constantly being killed by the health check, with an error:

`service CoreStack-CoreServiceA69F11F4-9ciFOoAL5oj9 (port 5000) is unhealthy in target-group CoreS-CoreS-FMLY84WTNYVN due to (reason Health checks failed with these codes: [404]).`

The code of the stack:

```
import { aws_ecs_patterns, Stack, StackProps } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { Repository } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecr';
import { ContainerImage } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs';
import { HostedZone } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-route53';
import { ApplicationProtocol } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-elasticloadbalancingv2';
import ec2 = require('aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2');
import ecs = require('aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs');

const DOMAIN_NAME = 'newordergame.com';
const SUBDOMAIN = 'core';
const coreServiceDomain = SUBDOMAIN + '.' + DOMAIN_NAME;

export class CoreStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'CoreServiceVpc', { maxAzs: 2 });

    const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, 'Cluster', { vpc });

    const repository = Repository.fromRepositoryName(
      this,
      'CoreServiceRepository',
      'core-service'
    );

    const image = ContainerImage.fromEcrRepository(repository, 'latest');

    const zone = HostedZone.fromLookup(this, 'NewOrderGameZone', {
      domainName: DOMAIN_NAME
    });

    // Instantiate Fargate Service with just cluster and image
    new aws_ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
      this,
      'CoreService',
      {
        cluster,
        taskImageOptions: {
          image: image,
          containerName: 'core',
          containerPort: 5000,
          enableLogging: true
        },
        protocol: ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
        domainName: coreServiceDomain,
        domainZone: zone
      }
    );
  }
}
```

The `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:16-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY webpack.config.js tsconfig.json ./
COPY src ./src
RUN npm run webpack:build
EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "node", "build/main.js" ]
```

The application also listens to the port `5000`.
It crashes every 3 mins.

Does anyone have a clue about how to fix it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your health check URL is returning a `404` status code. You need to configure the health check with a path that will return `200` status code.

Comment: Right now it's deployed here: `wss://core.newordergame.com`, and Postman along with the front end are connecting fine. The path should be `/` if I understood you right.

Comment: I don't think a load balancer health check is going to work against a wss:// URL. What are the actual target group health check settings when you look at them in the AWS web console?

Comment: Health check settings


Protocol = 
HTTP |


Path =
/ |


Port =
Traffic port |


Healthy threshold =
5 consecutive health check successes |


Unhealthy threshold =
2 consecutive health check failures |


Timeout =
5 seconds |


Interval =
30 seconds |


Success codes =
200

Comment: So an HTTP request to `/` is returning 404 apparently?

Comment: Yeah. Here's also HTTPS as an option.
I set it up, but it still stops...

Comment: I set it to `HTTP` `/` and set the Success codes to `404`.

It could be a temporary workaround, but not a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

ELB health check works only with **HTTP** or **HTTPS**, it does not work with **WebSocket** including Socket.io

So, the best workaround I found is to make the service **listen to the HTTP port** along with WebSocket and **answer it with status 200**.

With this approach, the health check will actually check the status of the service.